# It possible that two records has a same inserte's time in sql server, insert record by record throughput stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am developing a website. This site has a form with a field, this field permits a number, when a user sends this form, the backend takes this number and try to insert into a SQL Server table through a stored procedure:

1. User's Form

   ```
   using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = myId" }))
   {            
       @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.MyModel, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", autofocus = "" });
   }
   ```
2. Backend

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage ProcessNumber([FromBody] GeneralModel param)
   {
     ..some validation
     ..send data to store procedure
   }
   ```
3. Store Procedure

   ```
   INSERT INTO tblMyTable (key1, key2, NumberbyForm, DateCreated, DateModified)
   VALUES (key1, key2, @NumerByForm, getdate(), getdate())
   ```

Some days ago, I reviewed my table "tblMyTable" and found two rows with the same DateCreated and the same DateModified

[image]

- I believe that is very strange, how do those records have the same time, Datecreated?
- I have some methods to validate that they can not insert records with the same NumberbyForm, it seems that those records were inserted at the same time. and my method could not detect the existing record, before the insertion of the second record in the database
- I am inserting record by record in "insert into values ...", so only has a value, but I don't know how this happened?

Comment: Try to see where `DateCreated` and `DateModified` are inserted. May be they somewhere has code like this `ISNULL(DateCreated, GETDATE())` and  `ISNULL(DateModified, GETDATE())`

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. The `datetime` datatype has accuracy to 3 or 4 milliseconds as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . So definitely possible for 2 things to happen within 3 milliseconds of each other. _A common issue with websites is double submit - you can get scenarios like this by double clicking buttons on forms._

Comment: If the granularity is only to .001 seconds and two records are inserted within that amount of time then, yes, they would have the same date value.  The real question is... Why is this a problem?  If that's the time at which that record was created then that's the time at which that record was created.  What's the real question here?

Comment: Definitely sounds like an XY problem here. Are you trying to avoid data duplication using the DateCreated field? Or are you concerned that a user can submit duplicate data through the form? It's not clear, but it is definitely not strange or impossible to have 2 users enter data simultaneously (unless your application or database prevent this).

Comment: thank you @JacobH , i am try to avoid register duplicated in NumberbyForm, avoid that a user can submit duplicated data through the form, the DateCreated is just for audit

Comment: If you are trying to avoid duplicating data in that column, I would recommend adding a Unique Column Constraint or possibly including that integer in the primary key itself. This will cause the user to receive an error when a duplicate is entered. It should keep your data clean, and also help you troubleshoot this problem.